# WPF Chat application help C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, sockets, chat

I need some help here with a WPF chat application using sockets. The problem is it just doesn't seem to work so can someone please guide me what I'm doing wrong. below you will find my code in the code WPF code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace CSSChat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            textLocalIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
            textRemoteIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
        }

        //return own IP
        private string GetLocalIP()
        {
            string ipaddr = null;

            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    ipaddr = ip.ToString();
                    return ipaddr;
                }
            }

            //in case we didn't get it
            if (ipaddr == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("IP can not be null in GetLocalIP() ");
            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                EndPoint epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epRemote);

                //check if we got something
                byte[] recvdata = new byte[1464];
                recvdata = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;

                //convert to human-readable
                ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string recv_message = enc.GetString(recvdata);

                //adding message to the listbox
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    listMessages.Text += "Remote box: " + recv_message;
                    listMessages.Text += "\r\n";
                }));
            //start listening again
            byte[] buf = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buf, 0, buf.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                //bind socket
                try
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        EndPoint eplocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
                        sck.Bind(eplocal);

                        //connect to remote IP & Port
                        EndPoint epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textRemotePort.Text));
                        sck.Connect(epRemote);

                        //start listening
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1500];
                        sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buf, 0, buf.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buf);

                        //send
                        btnStart.Content = "Connected";
                        btnStart.IsEnabled = false;
                        textMessage.Focus();
                    }));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                //convert to human-readable 
                ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] buf = new byte[1500];
                buf = enc.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);

                //send message
                sck.Send(buf);

                //add to chat window
                    listMessages.Text += "Me: " + textMessage.Text;
                    listMessages.Text += "\r\n";

                    //clear
                    textMessage.Clear();
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you receiving any error?  Can you narrow down the code to just the part in question?

Comment: Hi, the application compiles smoothly without any errors. I'm just getting lost here, everything seems to be in tact but when I test it using either two instances on my local machine or on two different laptops it does not send or receive the messages on the remote computer.

Comment: Both machines are on the same subnet?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I tried both using the local Ips and the remote IP with redirecting the appropriate ports on my router.

Comment: Port redirects on the router only work for external traffic if memory serves.  On an internal subnet, your router wouldnt bother with redirecting.  This may not be your problem, but if you are expecting to redirect to another port, that could be the failure.  Also, make sure to [open up your port in Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall)

Comment: Hi, I tried with disabling the Windows firewall features on both computers - didn't work either.

Comment: I'm unable to set this up on multiple computers right now, but will be able to test it in a few hours.  If you havent solved it by then that is :)

Comment: Take a look at [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) in the mean time.  They can sniff the packets that each machine is sending and receiving. You should be able to get better visibility that way.

Comment: I resolved the situation by putting an invoker in the callback function. It seems that because of the UI updating too often in the callback I was getting a run-time notice that the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it, which means because the previous thread hadn't finished its job it and the callback function didn't do its job properly thus the data getting in received on the udp stream. A strange thing though, I was not able to sniff the data passing through the app with wireshark (or may be I missed it, even if i tried filtering the relevant ports).

Comment: Excellent, post your code as your own answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use an invoker and put all the events in either

```
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
... your code here ...
}));
```

or

```
//for asynchronous multithreading
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadsTart(() =>
{
...
}));
```

In the above code both do it.